# Portable Speaker Repair - Possible Battery Issue?

Tags: batteries, repair

I'm trying to diagnose why a portable, Bluetooth speaker (Otone Blufiniti) won't power on. I *think* the issue is the battery and could do with some help please.

So far, to diagnose the issue, I've:

1. Removed the internal battery and tried powering solely from the USB charging port. Didn't work.
2. Replaced the internal battery with a 7.4 V power supply. Didn't work.
3. Replaced the internal battery with a 7.4 V power supply and connected a power supply to the USB charging port. Did turn on, but no Bluetooth functionality (perhaps this is a separate issue, so I'm counting this as a success for the minute).

This is the battery:

[image: battery]

Some relevant voltage measurements:

- `B1+ & B1- = 2.47 V`
- `B2+ & B2- = 2.47 V`
- `P+  & P- = 0 V`

I thought `P+ & P-` should have some voltage across them, but that doesn't seem to be the case, am I correct to think this, as I'm a little unsure of what the yellow wire (`T`) is for? As far as I can tell, the yellow wire (`T`) isn't actually connected to anything either:

[image: battery connector underside]
[image: battery connector topside]

Thanks for taking the time to help me with this!

Comment: I suggest you add the model of the speaker to the question in case someone has (or already had and can help you) the same issue with the same model :)

Comment: Black is 0V Red = > >3V pref 3.6  Yellow = thermal sensor resistance. New battery and / or charge regulator is required. Does Pairing work?

Comment: Added the make/model, good idea!
@TonyStewartEE75 I take it the thermal sensor would be on the battery PCB? So maybe the main board isn't using that sensor if it's not connected? Pairing didn't work when I got it to turn on, but I was assuming that might be another issue, unless it's related somehow?

Comment: _”B1+ & B1- = 2.47v”_ That battery is probably not happy. If it were mine, I would charge each cell individually to 3.7 V and see if it comes back to life. If you don’t have experience with this and are aware of the dangers involved, I recommend against it.

Comment: Supply CM noise might be an issue , so charge up the batteries to 3.7V using 4.2 CC <1A and then CV to 10%CC then stop and repeat test without ext. PS then monitor Vbat for sag/charge

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Just measured the resistance across the black and yellow wires coming from the battery and I can see the resistance varying with the temperature now; thanks for the pointer. Seems to sit at about 12KOhm at room temperature. I'm not fussed about it being battery powered, so is it likely that I'd be able to power it from the USB port alone if I can disable the battery circuitry somehow?

Comment: _”P+  & P- = 0 V”_ OVLO of the BMS has triggered for sure.

Comment: @winny Will that "untrigger" if the battery was externally charged?

Comment: Depends on the BMS. Some do, others lock out forever.